# remove html from json data android studio

Tags: android, html, json, android-studio, web

i'm tried with my android studio project. i'm storing data from `wp-json` and everything is working fine. but - i'm getting something like that:

```
<p>আল্লামা আহমদ শফীর ইন্তেকালের পর চট্টগ্রামের দারুল উলুম মুঈনুল ইসলাম হাটহাজারী মাদরাসার আপাতত একক কোনো মহাপরিচালক নিযুক্ত করা হবে না। এর পরিবর্তে তিনজনের একটি পরিচালনা কমিটি করা হয়েছে।</p>\n<p>শনিবার আল্লামা শফীর জানাজার পর মাদরাসার শুরা কমিটির বৈঠকে এ সিদ্ধান্ত নেয়া হয়। এতে মাদরাসা পরিচালনার জন্য তিনজনকে নির্বাচন করা হয়েছে।</p>\n<p>এ তিনজন হলেন, পরিচালনা কমিটির প্রধান মুফতিয়ে আজম বাংলাদেশ আল্লামা মুফতি আব্দুস সালাম চাটগামী হাফিজাহুল্লাহু, আল্লামা শেখ আহমদ হাফিজাহুল্লাহ ও আল্লামা ইয়াহইয়া সাহেব হাফিজাহুল্লাহ।</p>\n<p>এছাড়া মাওলানা জুনায়েদ বাবুনগরীকে শিক্ষা পরিচালক ও শায়খুল হাদিস হিসেবে নিয়োগ দেয়া হয়েছে।<br />\nসহকারী শিক্ষা সচিব হিসবে নিয়োগ দেয়া হয়েছে আল্লামা হাফেজ শোয়াইব সাহেব হাফিজাহুল্লাহুকে।</p>\n<p>সূত্র জানায়, তিন সদস্য বিশিষ্ট এ কমিটি এখন থেকে হাটহাজারী মাদরাসার সব কাজের সুরাহা করবেন। তাদের সবার সমান অধিকার থাকবে। তাদের মধ্য থেকে কেউ একজন এককভাবে কোনো সিদ্ধান্ত নিতে পারবেন না।</p>\n<p>প্রসঙ্গত, শুক্রবার সন্ধ্যায় হাটহাজারী মাদ্রাসার দীর্ঘ ৩৪ বছরের মহাপরিচালক ও হেফাজতে ইসলামের আমির আল্লামা শাহ আহমদ শফী ইন্তেকাল করেন।</p>\n<p>শনিবার (১৯ সেপ্টেম্বর) বেলা ২টা ১৫ মিনিটে লাখো মুসুল্লির উপস্থিতিতে জানাজা শেষে মাদরাসা বাইতুল আতিক জামে মসজিদ সংলগ্ন ‘মাকবারাতুল জামিয়া’ নামক কবরস্থানে দাফন করা হয় আল্লামা শফীকে।</p>\n<p>ইউএইচ/</p>\n
```

here you can see `<p>\n` tags are showing. i want to show all of them html from my textview as like web. but i'm not understanding how i can do that. need to work html tags, but hide from plain text.

here is my java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String JSON_URL = "http://web.com/api.php";
    private JsonArrayRequest request ;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue ;
    private List<Anime> lstAnime ;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lstAnime = new ArrayList<>() ;
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);
        jsonrequest();
    }

    private void jsonrequest() {

        request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject  = null ;

                for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {


                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i) ;
                        Anime anime = new Anime() ;
                        anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        anime.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                        anime.setRating(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                        anime.setCategorie(jsonObject.getString("category"));
                        anime.setStudio(jsonObject.getString("admin"));
                        anime.setImage_url(jsonObject.getString("thumbnail"));
                        lstAnime.add(anime);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

                setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });


        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(request) ;


    }

    private void setuprecyclerview(List<Anime> lstAnime) {


        RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,lstAnime) ;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);

    }
}
```

here is my details activity.java

```
public class AnimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anime);

        // hide the default actionbar
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        // Recieve data

        String name  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_name");
        String description = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_description");
        String studio = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_studio") ;
        String category = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_category");
        int nb_episode = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("anime_nb_episode") ;
        String rating = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_rating") ;
        String image_url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_img") ;

        // ini views

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.collapsingtoolbar_id);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true);

        TextView tv_name = findViewById(R.id.aa_anime_name);
        TextView tv_studio = findViewById(R.id.aa_studio);
        TextView tv_categorie = findViewById(R.id.aa_categorie) ;
        TextView tv_description = findViewById(R.id.aa_description);
        TextView tv_rating  = findViewById(R.id.aa_rating) ;
        ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.aa_thumbnail);

        // setting values to each view

        tv_name.setText(name);
        tv_categorie.setText(category);
        tv_description.setText(description);
        tv_rating.setText(rating);
        tv_studio.setText(studio);

        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(name);

        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);

        // set image using Glide
        Glide.with(this).load(image_url).apply(requestOptions).into(img);
    }
}
```

i want to do that with `tv_description` textview.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show `HTML` in `tv_description` in your `AnimeActivity` following code will work.

```
public class AnimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anime);

        // hide the default actionbar
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        // Recieve data

        String name  = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_name");
        String description = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_description");
        String studio = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_studio") ;
        String category = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_category");
        int nb_episode = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("anime_nb_episode") ;
        String rating = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_rating") ;
        String image_url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("anime_img") ;

        // ini views

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.collapsingtoolbar_id);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true);

        TextView tv_name = findViewById(R.id.aa_anime_name);
        TextView tv_studio = findViewById(R.id.aa_studio);
        TextView tv_categorie = findViewById(R.id.aa_categorie) ;
        TextView tv_description = findViewById(R.id.aa_description);
        TextView tv_rating  = findViewById(R.id.aa_rating) ;
        ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.aa_thumbnail);

        // setting values to each view

        tv_name.setText(name);
        tv_categorie.setText(category);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            tv_description.setText(Html.fromHtml(description, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        } else {
            tv_description.setText(Html.fromHtml(description));
        }
        tv_rating.setText(rating);
        tv_studio.setText(studio);

        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(name);

        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);

        // set image using Glide
      
        Glide.with(this).load(image_url)
            .apply(requestOptions).into(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: where i can place this code? can you edit with my code or give me instruction?

Comment: Put this code where you set text in your text view. You've not given that code in question. So I can't edit your code. Please provide codesnap where you want to show this information.

Comment: i'm added my code for details activity. please see that code

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check updated answer.

Comment: woow...! you are great! it's solve my issue. but i have one more problem. `<a href="">title</a>` is not working. how i can make it clickable? if someone click on the link, it will open a webview.

Comment: In that case, you have to build `Spannable` string manually.

Comment: any tutorial link please?